# vscode appears to be ignoring pipeTransport config

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a dotnet core container in vscode. I'm on macOS.

This is my task:

```
{
    "name": "Docker .NET Core Launch",
    "type": "docker",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
    "netCore": {
        "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/myproject/myapp.csproj"
    },
    //https://github.com/sleemer/docker.dotnet.debug
    "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "docker",
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceFolder}/myapp",
        "pipeArgs": [
            "exec -i container-name"
        ],
        "quoteArgs": false,
        "debuggerPath": "/vsdbg/vsdbg"
    }
}
```

When I run the debug task it fails and I see this output:

```
Starting: "docker" exec -i container-name /remote_debugger/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode
Error from pipe program 'docker': Error response from daemon: Container f63352bfb263a6005b00caf14b50d1b7af6681b3dce1cd530c674699dd8fca57 is not running
The pipe program 'docker' exited unexpectedly with code 1.
```

It seems like it's totally ignoring `pipeArgs`. It's using `/remote_debugger/vsdbg`. Also, anything else I put in `pipeArgs` does not appear to be added to the command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the pipeArgs needs to be one argument per item in the list. Like this...

```
   "pipeArgs": [
            "exec",
            "-i",
            "container-name"
        ]
```